# Matplotlib: how to make tight_layout independent of ticklabels

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

Here is part of my code, which exports figures with tight layout.

```
   ...
  fig.set_size_inches(8,6.8)
  fig.tight_layout(rect=(0, 0, 1, 0.9))
 # fig.savefig(path,bbox_inches='tight',dpi=100)
  fig.savefig(path,dpi=100)         
  plt.gcf().clear()
  plt.close(fig)
   ...
```

Unfortunately when I looping over different frames and y axis labels are changing, there are frames when ticklabels getting very close to the edge and then entire plot is shrinked as shown in figures between red and green lines.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/248943005/Montage.png

I tried several cases, but this effect is always coming up in one or another way. It seems like it would be good to make tight layout somehow independent of ticklabels. Is that possible? If no, are there alternatives?

Comment: the _point_ of tight_layout is to take the tick labels into account.

Comment: so how to avoid that?

Comment: Don't use `tight_layout`.  The reason `tight_layout` exists is to make it easy to ensure that all of your text falls with in the bounding box of the figure and doesn't get cut off when you save it (you get somewhat strange issues with re-sizing the figure + fonts in fixed points, they need more fractional space the smaller the figure is).

Comment: So, what would be alternative to tight_layout to get plots fixed to figure with no large empty margins?

Comment: Your link is dead. Adjust the axis size see `subplots_adjust`.

Comment: Thanks, subplots_adjust works like a charm. Great answer. Umm, I just checked link, for me it works perfectly. I use Chrome browser by the way.